# Magento API access on localhost without using internet connection

Tags: php, api, magento

I have installation of magento 1.6.1 on local machine i\’m trying to connect magetno\’s api in php using following code

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiuser', 'apikey');
```

I can connect using this code if internet connection on, If I make it off it doesn't work.
it gives following errors

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\wamp\www\magentomanager\api\products.php on line 12

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in E:\wamp\www\magentomanager\api\products.php on line 12
```

please let me know what is the reason behind that?. 
why magento needed internet connection for accessing local api. how do I access api without having without internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento's API is based on SOAP, as you may have found out. SOAP is based on XML and uses therefor schema files, which desribes the schema/layout for the SOAP calls for this service. So this file might be loaded before/on every SOAP call.

However, a workaorund could be to store the schema description on your local machine and editing Magento's wsdl.xml files, so that they will reference to your local machine. Simply search for the URL in all xml files inside your Magento installation.

Not a very nice workaround, but hey,... it's a workaround.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but changing magento's code is a pain, it is distributed in so many files, I'm afraid if I change something it may break in some other part, I even tried creating virtual host for this url http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ which api calls looking for and returning desired xml for it. but it is also not helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that localhost can't be resolved to your local IP or 127.0.0.1. You can add it in your host file or call it thru http:/// instead of http://localhost

Comment: Yes, it would indeed be possible to serve those files from a local web server by using the hosts file to point 127.0.0.1 to schemas.xmlsoap.org).